# Sequence of vectors with specific conditions forming a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$E$ is a vector space with $e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}, e_{4}, e_{5} \in E$ with the following conditions:

1. $E = \langle e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}, e_{4}, e_{5} \rangle$.
2. $ e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}, e_{4}, e_{5} $ are linearly dependent.
3. $ e_{1} + e_{2}, e_{2} + e_{3}, e_{3} $ are linearly independent and don't generate $E$.
4. $ e_{1} + e_{4}, e_{2}, e_{3} + e_{4}$ are linearly dependent.

I need to use this information to show that $(e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}, e_{5})$ is a basis of $E$, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cool problem. Set $V=\langle e_1+e_2,e_2+e_3,e_3 \rangle$ and $W=\langle e_1+e_4,e_2,e_3+e_4 \rangle$, and set $X=\langle W,e_4\rangle$. Finally, set $Z = \langle e_1,e_2,e_3,e_5 \rangle$; we're trying to prove that $Z=E$.

- Note that $V = \langle e_1,e_2,e_3 \rangle$ and $X = \langle e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4 \rangle = \langle V,e_4\rangle$.

Now we do some dimension-counting.

- From 1 and 2, we know that $\dim E < 5$.
- From 3, we know that $\dim E > 3$. Therefore $\dim E = 4$. To prove that $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_5$ is a basis for $E$, it suffices to prove that $\dim Z\ge 4$.
- From 3, we know that $\dim V = 3$.
- From 4, we know that $\dim W < 3$. It follows that $\dim X \le \dim W + \dim \langle e_4 \rangle \le \dim W + 1 < 4$. Therefore $V\subseteq X$ but $\dim X \le 3 = \dim V$, and therefore $V=X$. It follows that $e_4$ is a linear combination of $e_1,e_2,e_3$.
- Finally, $V\subseteq Z$; if $\dim Z \le 3 = \dim V$, then it would follow that $e_5$ is a linear combination of $e_1,e_2,e_3$. But since $e_4$ is also, it would follow that $\dim E \le 3$, a contradiction. Therefore $\dim Z > 3$, as required.

Comment: How do you know that $dimE > 3$ from 3?

Comment: because of the "and don't generate $E$" phrase

Comment: But shouldn't that just tell you that it is different from 3?

Comment: More precisely, the fact we're using is that the dimension of any vector space ($E$ in this case) is at least as large as the size of any linearly independent subset of that vector space. (It's also at most as large as the size of any spanning subset.) Maybe we're also using the fact that if $S\subset E$ is linearly independent but doesn't span $E$, then there exists a vector $x\in E$ such that $S\cup \{x\}$ is also linearly independent.

Comment: You'r right. Thanks

Comment: When you say: "(...) To prove that $e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}, e_{5}$ is a basis for $E$, it suffices to prove that $dimZ ≥ 4$ " shouldn't we have to prove that $e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}, e_{5}$ are linearly independent?

Comment: Both are valid methods of proof (as would be proving that $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_5$ span $E$).